# Select columns into rows for export

Tags: sql-server, select, unpivot

I have a database table called 'transactions' with multiple columns.  For each transactions row i need to produce an export with one row per column from a specified list

Transactions table

```
ID, DoNotEmail, DoNotMail, DoNotPhone, DoNotSMS
1000, true,    false,      true,       true
```

The following rules need to apply.

DoNotEmail is set then output 'DNE'

DoNotMail is set then output 'DNM'

DoNotPhone is set then output 'DNP'

DoNotSMS is set then output 'DNS'

The export needs to look like:

```
ID, Suppressions
1000,  DNE
1000,  DNP
1000,  DNS
```

Im getting really confused and the only way i can get it working is really horrible with a insert statement for every column into two temp tables.  Urgh.

Is this possible please?

Thanks for any help.

Darren

p.s. sorry about the formatting.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 6):

This will probably work if you only have four columns:

```
SELECT id, 
       'DNE' AS Suppressions 
FROM   transactions 
WHERE  donotemail = 'true' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 
       'DNM' AS Suppressions 
FROM   transactions 
WHERE  donotmail = 'true' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 
       'DNP' AS Suppressions 
FROM   transactions 
WHERE  donotphone = 'true' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 
       'DNS' AS Suppressions 
FROM   transactions 
WHERE  donotsms = 'true'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/799c86/1)

Comment: Hi, ive got about 30+ columns !!

Comment: @DarrenRhymer What platform are you using? MySQL, SQL Server?

Comment: @DarrenRhymer 30+ columns or otherwise, you can take the pattern established by this answer or by bluefeet's answer, and run with it.

Comment: @DarrenRhymer No such thing as SQL Server 2010. It could be 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 or 2012.

Comment: Sorry my mistake SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 6):

Another way this can be written is:

```
SELECT id,
  case col 
    when 'DoNotEmail' then 'DNE'
    when 'DoNotMail' then 'DNM'
    when 'DoNotPhone' then 'DNP'
    when 'DoNotSMS' then 'DNS'
  end Suppressions
FROM 
(
  SELECT t.ID,
    s.col,
    CASE s.col
      WHEN 'DoNotEmail' THEN DoNotEmail
      WHEN 'DoNotMail' THEN DoNotMail
      WHEN 'DoNotPhone' THEN DoNotPhone
      WHEN 'DoNotSMS' THEN DoNotSMS
    END AS DATA
  FROM Transactions t
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 'DoNotEmail' AS col
    UNION ALL SELECT 'DoNotMail'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'DoNotPhone'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'DoNotSMS'
  ) s
) s
where data = 'true';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5bde2/14).

Since you are using SQL Server, you can implement the `UNPIVOT` function:

```
select id,
  case col 
    when 'DoNotEmail' then 'DNE'
    when 'DoNotMail' then 'DNM'
    when 'DoNotPhone' then 'DNP'
    when 'DoNotSMS' then 'DNS'
  end Suppressions
from Transactions
unpivot
(
  value 
  for col in ([DoNotEmail], [DoNotMail], [DoNotPhone], [DoNotSMS])
) piv
where value = 'true'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0161/3)

Comment: @DarrenRhymer see my edit, I included a version that uses the `unpivot` function.  This will minimize the lines of code needed to get the result.

Answer (score 4):

This will work in SQL Server 2008 or later. It can be modified to work on SQL Server 2005 as well if you need that.

```
select T1.ID,
       T2.Name
from Transactions as T1
  cross apply (values (DoNotEmail, 'DNE'), 
                      (DoNotMail,  'DNM'), 
                      (DoNotPhone, 'DNP'), 
                      (DoNotSMS,   'DNS')
              ) as T2(Value, Name)
where T2.Value = 'true'
```

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, it looks nice. Looking at the query plan it does about the same as both your versions. One table scan with join against a constant scan of four rows so there should be no real difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but Ive implemented this one and it works a treat.  Thanks Mikael

Answer (score 1):

A `CROSS JOIN` on a four record table saves having to scan the table four times.  bluefeet posted an answer using this first (+1).  Here is a similar version using Oracle.

```
SELECT id, Suppressions FROM
(
  SELECT id, 
     CASE 
        WHEN Col = 1 AND donotemail = 'true' THEN 'DNE'
        WHEN Col = 2 AND donotmail  = 'true' THEN 'DNM'
        WHEN Col = 3 AND donotphone = 'true' THEN 'DNP'
        WHEN Col = 4 AND donotsms   = 'true' THEN 'DNS'
        ELSE NULL
     END Suppressions 
  FROM Transactions
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT Level Col FROM dual CONNECT BY Level <=4)
)
WHERE Suppressions IS NOT NULL;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/799c8/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, 'DNE' as 'Suppressions'
from transactions
where DoNotEmail = 'true'
UNION ALL
select ID, 'DNM' as 'Suppressions'
from transactions
where DoNotMail = 'true'
UNION ALL
select ID, 'DNS' as 'Suppressions'
from transactions
where DoNotPhone = 'true'
UNION ALL
select ID, 'DNE' as 'Suppressions'
from transactions
where DoNotSMS = 'true'
order by ID
```